# Steps for building a page with active directory authentication

Tags: asp.net, active-directory

Need direction and help in active directory authentication
I want to build a web page which is able to identify a person accessing the web page by comparing the active directory email feild to the one in our application contact table and show the necessary functionality.

What are the steps i need to follow to acheive the above